# Calculate the gaussian kernel density in python

Tags: python, gaussian

I have a list of integer, what is the best way to calculate the gaussian kernel density in python? Library?

Comment: Did you try : sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity ?

Comment: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/ talks about *three* libraries to do this: Scipy, Statsmodels, and scikit-learn. Enjoy…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr Vanderplas has written a blog post detailing how to do this with three separate libraries: [Kernel Density Estimation in Python](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/):

- Scipy,
- Statsmodels, and
- scikit-learn.

Should be a good start.